# Lost /boot partition

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-xp

Recently I installed Windows XP on my machine where I had only Ubuntu. The problem is that I had my `/boot` on a separate, 200 Mb partition at beginning of the hard-disk (the leftmost). Installing windows, it said that it can't write MBR because there's an unknown partition, so I formatted that partition as NTFS, and I could finally get windows installed. Now I want to restore that partition so I can use my Linux keeping both systems.

Now should I install grub2 there, or it's OK by restoring partition data? If the first is the correct answer then provide me a little tutorial on installing it. Keep in mind that there was my `/boot` folder.

Comment: no imho - in this case what to do if windows was installed and /boot partition was completely deleted

Comment: Related question: [How do I restore a linux boot partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2558/how-do-i-restore-a-linux-boot-partition)

Comment: I see, just leaving it in here as a point of reference

Answer (score 1):

First get a copy of a Windows 98 Startup Disk that has fdisk on it (it will repair the MBR if GRUB has errors see down this text).

You should start the live cd (the same cd as the version installed), chroot into the partition of linux (man chroot) and from there (not sure if it will work):

sudo nano /etc/fstab       ->  remove the /boot entry

sudo mkdir /boot

sudo apt-get install -y linux grub2

sudo init 6

If this did not work and Windows does not start any more, insert the Windows 98 Startup Disk, boot from it and in the command line do:

fdisk /mbr

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I guess I should mount first my /sdax (boot partition) first to /boot, right? Also I saw that actually grub2 is a dummy package and the right one is grub-pc.

Comment: OK, I found the official documentation on how to do this :D
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20GRUB%202