# Windows 8 messed me up

Tags: grub2, windows-8

I installed windows 8 on my computer and ruined my Ubuntu partition. Now I can't get my Grub to come up. Here's the catch, I installed Ubuntu inside windows and I even tried the fix that was given on the forums right here, [Dedicated GRUB2 Partition and Windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61362/dedicated-grub2-partition-and-windows-8).

That didn't work. Would a complete reinstall of Ubuntu be the only fix? I'm totally lost and I'm already getting sick and tired of Windows 8 :p.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! When you say you "installed Ubuntu inside Windows", do you mean you used the Wubi installer?

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is solved by reinstalling grub. For this you need to boot from your Ubuntu live CD and opening the terminal will allow you access to reinstall grub.

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20GRUB%202) is
some documentation.

Comment: I tried this, but I kept getting this:
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda2
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for /mnt/boot/grub (is /dev mounted?).
I even tried boot-repair, but it would only let me repair MBR because all of my partitions are technically windows.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry! I've had this exact same problem before! Your installation is fine!

Simply boot into your computer using your Live CD (and also back-up files if you wish to do so now). Then, reinstall or update your GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

Dont panic.When you install Windows, Windows assumes it's the only OS on the machine—or at least it doesn't account for Linux. So, it replaces GRUB with its own bootloader.

What you have to do is to replace the Windows bootloader with GRUB. Simply chroot into your install and run update-grub.

[Here's how: How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/88432#88432)

See this as well
[Similar question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/494601/windows-8-fails-to-load-after-boot-repair/494610#494610)